# jquery change() vs keyup()

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am currently having a problem with the `keyup()` event.

When I use my autocomplete with the `.change()` event everything is working fine. But the suggestions of the autocomplete are only showing when losing the focus of the field which is normal, I think.

The problem is when I use the `.keyup()` event, the suggestions are shown but when you CLICK on an item from the suggested list the item is not put in the Textfield.

Unlike the `change()` function which sets the suggestions to the field.

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {  
        jQuery("#customfield_10000").keyup(function(e){
                            teller = teller + 1;
                            if(teller % 2 == 0){
                            if(e.keyCode == 13)
                            {
                                jQuery("#customfield_10001").focus();
                            }    

            crmAccount = jQuery(this).val();
            lijstAccounts.length = 0;

                    jQuery.ajax({
                        url: "http://"+serverIp+"/getAllAccountNamesJsonP?jsonp_callback=?",
                        dataType: 'jsonp',
                        jsonp: "jsonp_callback",
                        data: {
                            featureClass: "P",
                            style: "full",
                            maxRows: 12,
                            name_startsWith: jQuery(this).val(),
                                                            crm_acc: crmAccount,
                            },
                            success: function( data ) {
                                lijstAccounts.length = 0;
                                 jQuery.map( data, function( item ) {
                                                            lijstAccounts.push(item);
                                                            jQuery('#customfield_10000').trigger(
                                                                'setSuggestions',
                                                            { result : textext.itemManager().filter(lijstAccounts, query)

                                                                                                                            }
                                                            );              
                                    return {
                                        label: item.label,
                                        value: item.value    
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }); 
                            }
        });


             jQuery('#customfield_10000').textext({
                plugins : 'autocomplete'
                }).bind('getSuggestions', function(e, data)
                    {

                        textext = jQuery(e.target).textext()[0],
                        query = (data ? data.query : '') || '';

                    });
});
```

Comment: Personally i never use "change" event because it get fired when you lose focus of control.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you just bind both? Depending on your jQuery version:

jQuery 1.7+

```
$(selector).on('keyup change', function() {});
```

Others

```
$(selector).bind('keyup change', function() {});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but binding them both is still not solving my problem. The clicked value only get set when using the change(). And the value should be set with keyup()

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem today actually, I changed my selector from referencing the id of the input field to the name like so:

```
$("input:text[name=search-box]").keyup(function(){
    //Code
});
```

Strangely enough after I made the change everything worked fine. Hope this works for you too.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This also gives all possibl values but on click it's not setting the value to the input field.